# dom4j add new elements to the document, no change happened in the doc

Tags: element, addition, dom4j

**xml structure:**

```
 <factory id= "1">
   <hall id= "101">
      <line id= "10101">
      </line>
```

want to add a new element, location under line. and to be:

```
 <factory id= "1">
   <hall id= "101">
     <line id= "10101">
       <location id= "123"></location>
     </line>
```

**java**

```
String path;
Document doc = null;

path = "./webapp/WEB/config/aaaaa.xml";

try {

SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
doc = reader.read(path);

} catch (DocumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String insertPointPath = "//abc/ddd/factory[@id='1']/hall[@id='101']/line[@id='10101']";
Element insertPoint = (Element) doc.selectSingleNode(insertPointPath);
insertPoint.addElement("location").addAttribute("id", "123");
```

the new element was added under "line" node, observed during debug. 
however, the document did not change. new element is not there.

**why the changes are not saved in the document?**

Comment: Did you actually save the document back to file?

Comment: yeah, i found that. the doc should be written back.